# Images being found on website load but not loaded correctly (broken)

Tags: html, image, path, opencart, src

Have this weird case when my images are being found in sources, linked correctly, src url is okay, but still not being displayed. Other images in that same folder are being loaded and displayed just fine, but my new uploaded images are not. I'm using open cart and upload images via ftp. Permissions are fine 644 like the others. I asked other developers in my team and no one has any clue why is that. Guys tried downlaoding and opening the image on their computer and can't even open it, whereas I'm using MAC and can open the same images on my computer without any problems. Images are saved as .jpg from Photoshop. What's the deal here? Here is how it looks in Mozilla:

[image]

Comment: please share the website `url` where this is occurring?

Comment: try to download a image from google and so the same , i think this is a Photoshop problem.

Comment: Yeah it was, first time I just did save as in Photoshop and made it jpg format. Then yesterday I tried doing export instead and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because of corrupted image file. Most likely it is the extension problem of the file. Instead of doing save as in Photoshop, try exporting the image through export settings and choose png or jpg format there. It should work fine now, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure on this front - Are you uploading them as .JPG or .jpg? If so, the problem may lie there...

If you link to a file that is .jpg and you put .JPG into the code for the link, the link will not work.

Make sure you're not using uppercase JPG as some servers will not read/detect them, and you will not able to see the pictures until you change the extension to lower case jpg.

Also, make sure the color mode, if saving them from Photoshop directly to jpg, is RGB format. If you use any other color mode, it may not display at all. CMYK files for example will not display correctly.